# Second indexed key has stage of "COLLSCAN" in Mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

I have a collection "Posts" and I indexed 2 keys in this collections:

```
"has_checked" : Array ,
"author_id"   : String
```

When I try to find with "has_checked" it`s fine and in mode explain("executionStats") it shows me:

```
"stage" : "IXSCAN" ,
"totalDocsExamined" : 1
```

But when I try to find with "author_id" it shows me:

```
"totalDocsExamined" : 36988,
"stage" : "COLLSCAN",
   "filter" : {
      "author_id" : {
         "$eq" : "597a2f9273519a27769f1b30"
       }
    }
```

and this is result of " db.posts.getIndexes()"

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "mydb.posts"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "has_checked" : 1,
                    "owner_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "has_checked_1_author_id_1",
            "ns" : "mydb.posts"
    }
```

]

Why it does not use author_id as indexed key?

Answer (score 0):

Mongo does not use author_id for query because It does not belong to any index prefix

Giving a example, If you have a compound index like this

```
{ "item": 1, "location": 1, "stock": 1 }
```

The index has the following index prefixes:

- { item: 1 }
- { item: 1, location: 1 }

For a compound index, MongoDB can use the index to support queries on the index prefixes. As such, MongoDB can use the index for queries on the following fields

- the item field,
- the item field and the location field,
- the item field and the location field and the stock field.

MongoDB can also use the index to support a query on item and stock fields since item field corresponds to a prefix. However, the index would not be as efficient in supporting the query as would be an index on only item and stock.

You can follow this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes to have more details

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted

```
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "mydb.posts"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "has_checked" : 1,
                    "owner_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "has_checked_1_author_id_1",
            "ns" : "mydb.posts"
    }

]
```

we can see two things:

That you have as an index the default which is `_id` and cannot be dropped. (For more information see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/))

> You cannot drop the default index on the _id field.

And your second index is `has_checked` with ascending order as well as `owner_id` also with ascending order.

The name of the compound index is unfortunate though. `"name" : "has_checked_1_author_id_1"`
This is only the index name and it doesn't mean that it's necessary the index as well. It usually if not always matches the key, but since we are only humans, mistakes happen.

Just check for the key next time and not the name. The name should be, but not always is representative of what the actual index key is.

I'd also recommend to rename it from `"has_checked_1_author_id_1"` to `"has_checked_1_owner_id_1"`. If you are making many queries to the `author_id` then maybe it's also a good idea to add another index.